# How to make a forked repo have the same stars and watchers as the original repo if I contributed to the organization

Tags: git, github, version-control

I want to have a organization repository in my github.Everytime I fork I am missing the stars and watchers.

How to include the organization repository with or without forking

Answer (score 1):

**It works as it is designed to do.**

The stars and watchers stay with the original repository. They are other people following the original repo they are not interested in your fork

Comment: the other developers have stars visible in the overview section whereas I dont find them in mine

Answer (score 0):

As the [Stars API illustrates](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/), watchers and stars can be for original or forked repositories: the JSON response will include: `fork: false` or true depending on the repository nature.

Third-party analytics tools might consider adding those to forks, as in [`chaoss/grimoirelab` issue 184](https://github.com/chaoss/grimoirelab/issues/184), but GitHub itself will not, and keep stars/watchers separate between original and forked repositories.

For instance:

- [`fossasia/susper.com`](https://github.com/fossasia/susper.com) is an original repository with 23 watchers, 1132 stars and 319 forks.
- [`0x48piraj/susper.com`](https://github.com/0x48piraj/susper.com) is a fork with one watcher and 3 stars

Comment: I want stars to appear in overview section

Comment: @kritikarao "the other developers have stars visible in the overview section ": for forked repositories? or for original repositories?

Comment: Its for original repositories and its visible in overview section

Comment: @kritikarao Yes: original repositories only: you would not see stars/watcher in the overhead section of a *forked* repository.

Comment: I see it in the forked repository whereas stars are for original repositories in the overview of the rest of developers.And there is no `forked from A` visible in the overview

Comment: @kritikarao you said other developers are seeing it for original repositories. Do you have the URL of a forked repository where you do see stars/watchers?

Comment: @kritikarao "there is no forked from A visible in the overview": that means it is an original repository, not a fork: you would then see stars/watchers.

Comment: Its not original repository for sure. Upon clicking `Type:Sources` it doesn't appear

Comment: @kritikarao Do you have its URL? Is it a public repository that I can see?

Comment: @kritikarao looks like an original repo. I do see stars though for https://github.com/0x48piraj/susper.com, which is a fork.

Comment: Check the overview of github.com/0x48piraj and see https://github.com/fossasia/Connect-Me   stars and forks are visible in overview

Comment: @kritikarao I see stars/watchers, but it is not a forked repositories though.

Comment: Is it possible to get them with or without forking in overview

Comment: @kritikarao Do you have an example of a fork where you do not see them?

Comment: Convinced that forks won't be having stars. Can you help in getting stars/forks visible in overview

Comment: @kritikarao I have edited the answer to show you a fork which does have its own set of watchers/stars.